# Noexec mount - Refusing to exec ERROR when loading Crouton from command line

Tags: mount, chromebook, crouton

I have loaded Crouton on my Chromebook many times in the past, but...
I Powerwashed today to fix glitchy touchpad ---
When trying to access crouton file in Downloads I get a noexec mount error. ---
(No idea why the directory is suddenly noexec after years of use) ---
I saw what looked like a really good fix here on AskUbuntu Stack Exchange using
"sudo mount -o remount,exec,suid,dev,symfollow /home/chronos/user/Downloads/"
but it didn't work for me. --- I got:
"mount point not mounted or bad option"

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to the Chrome OS website shown on the same message it is stated that google made the shell to enforce `noexec` mounts which seems to be pretty much the whole drive. Except for `/usr/local`, which they left for development mode to remain exec.

So...

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/crouton /usr/local
```

and then run the script

```
sudo sh /usr/local/crouton -t unity
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it was

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/crouton /usr/local
```

and then

```
sudo sh -e /usr/local/crouton -t touch,xfce
```

Why? Because `-e` is for encryption and `xfce` because unity doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was

```
sudo sh /usr/local/crouton -t touch,xfce
```

because I have a touch chromebook.

[Acer Chromebook R11](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/HK/content/series/acerchromebookr11)